# How do I turn this "normal" array into a pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My C knowledge is young, so forgive me :) Two questions really,

1. How do I turn the following code into something that correctly makes use of `pthread_t *threadsArray` as opposed to `threadsArray[MAXCON]`?
2. Is there a good reason to? I've heard I should avoid using explicit arrays and try to use pointer defined arrays when I can.

`pthread_t threadsArray[MAXCON];`

```
int k;
for (k = 0; k < MAXCON; k++) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Make %d\n", k);

    int *connfd = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *connfd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen);
    if (*connfd == -1) {
        perror("Unable to accept connection");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Waited\n");

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, readWriteToClient, connfd);
    threadsArray[k] = thread;
}

for(k = 0; k < MAXCON; k++){
    fprintf(stderr,"Join %d\n",k);
    pthread_t thread = threadsArray[k];
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}
```

Comment: what problem are you having? (apart from lines 16..18, which you should _not_ do; instead use `pthread_create(threadsArray+k,...)`

Comment: No problem per se, just asking the question to learn from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question first: it sounds like you're talking about the different between stack and heap allocation.

Declaring the array in the function body like you've done will take up space on the stack, which can be quite limited (a few kilobytes to a few megabytes).

An alternative to this is to allocate the array on the "heap", which is limited only by the available memory in your computer. To allocate memory on the heap, you use `malloc()`.

So changing the first line to:

```
pthread_t *threadsArray = malloc(MAXCON * sizeof(pthread_t));
```

(and possibly checking for NULL if your system's malloc can fail)

is all you need to do to allocate the array on the heap.

You'll also need to do `free(threadsArray)` afterwards to release the memory.

But if MAXCON is small, allocating the array on the stack as you have done should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to use dynamically allocated memory (ie. memory from the heap) for your array instead of memory from the stack. This is generally useful when you want your array lifetime to be greater than the containing function or when you don't know the size it will have at compilation time.

For that, you just have to change your code by replacing the first lines with:

```
pthread_t *threadsArray;
threadsArray = (pthread_t*)malloc(MAXCON * sizeof(pthread_t));
// malloc may fails and return NULL, you must check this error condition
// and handle it properly (aborting the program, using a smaller array, ...)
```

And after your done using your array, you'll have to release the memory with:

```
free(threadArray);
threadArray = NULL;
```